# jQuery validation not working when input fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I think this is not complex one but I can't do it by myself. I am very thankful for your help.

I am going to submit a form with validation. It seems like my validations are not working properly. Because when the input fields are empty it's not showing an error message. And also when clicking the submit button it's not showing error message. This incident only happens when input fields are empty.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form name="department" id="department">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="example-text-input">Department Name</label>
        <span id="errfnCustomer"></span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Department Name" id="textDepartmentName" name="textDepartmentName1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="example-text-input">Registation Number</label>
        <span id="errfnCustomer2"></span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Department Registation Number" id="textRegistationNumber" name="textRegistationNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="example-text-input">Web Site</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Web Site" id="textWebsite" name="textWebsite1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn pull-right" id="btnsubmit" style="background-color:#1e90ff; width: 100px; color: white; font-weight: bold" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#department').validate({
    rules: {
        textDepartmentName1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
        },
        textRegistationNumber: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        textWebsite1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        }

    },
    submitHandler: $("#btnsubmit").click(function (form) {
        var submitData = {
            DepartmentId: saveStat,
            DepartmentName: $('#textDepartmentName').val().trim(),
            RegistationNumber: $('#textRegistationNumber').val(),
            Website: $('#textWebsite').val(),
            Email: $('#textEmail').val(),
            Telephone01: $('#textTelephone01').val(),
            Telephone02: $('#textTelephone02').val(),
            Fax: $('#textFax').val(),
            BranchId: $('#cmbGetBranch').val()
        }

        if (saveStat == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: "{submitData:" + JSON.stringify(submitData) + "}",
                url: "/Department/AddDepartment",
                success: function (saveDepartment) {
                    if (saveDepartment.saveDepartment.DepartmentId != 0) {
                        refresh();
                        alert(saveDepartment.saveDepartment.DepartmentName + " Saved succesfully...!!!");
                    } else {
                        alert('warning' + " Department saving unsucsessful...!!!");

                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error...!!! Internal - 01');
                }

            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: "{submitData:" + JSON.stringify(submitData) + "}",
                url: "/Department/UpdateDepartment",
                success: function (updateDepartment) {
                    if (updateDepartment.updateDepartment.DepartmentId != "") {
                        alert(updateDepartment.updateDepartment.DepartmentName + " updated succesfully...!!!");
                        refresh();
                    } else {
                        alert("Department update error...!!!");
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error...!!!');
                }
            });
        }
        grid();
    })
});
```

Comment: I think you need to pass `required` in you input's HTML.

Comment: I just add required attribute but it does not work

Comment: Like `<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Department Name" id="textDepartmentName" name="textDepartmentName1" required>`

Comment: I think issue is with your submitHandler. You dont need selector there. Simply "submitHandler: function(form){}" . See documentation here https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler

Comment: the  problem was  occur when there button type not submit. i got another help to find it. and thank you helping me you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make register buttom type submit:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn pull-right" id="btnsubmit" style="background-color:#1e90ff; width: 100px; color: white; font-weight: bold" />
```

And make submit handler something like this:

```
submitHandler:function (form) {

}
```

See more here ([Jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)).

Comment: This is not an answer... This should be a comment

Comment: This is a answer. I am just  updating this.

Comment: Thanks. when i change the button type to submit it's workig. and thanks again

Comment: Welcome mate..Even though it's working with changing button type, you need to change submiHadler as well.

Comment: Thanks mate. I changed also submiHadler  it's working great. But i thought Submit button id should there. that's why in used click event. if you can explain how it work without click event

Comment: There should be submit event rather than click event. Since you are using Jquery validation plugin this is the way to submit form. Jquery validation manages that all to submit your form.

Comment: Thanks again buddy.

Comment: can i get another help?

Comment: why not if i can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135145/discussion-between-thilina-gg-and-manohar-khadka).

Comment: stackoverflow suggest to go chat. so i put my problem in to chat. did u get it?